# Error when opening a java file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When opening an already existing java file in eclipse I am getting the following error. few days back it was opening correctly.

```
Could not open the editor: failure 'java.io.IOException: Break Iterator Rule Data Magic Number Incorrect, or unsupported data version.'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you open any other java files?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: I am not able to open any java files. When using Right Click and open with text editor its opening, but default editor is not working so I am unable to use debugger. Tried restarting the eclipse. Still no change.

Comment: Frankly, I feel that the easiest way right now would be a reinstall of Eclipse... some environment variable seems to have gone bad, but I don't have a clue which one and how to repair it, other than the reinstall.

Comment: Yes, after reinstalling it works fine. Still not sure what caused the issue. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, reinstall. :-)